# ASP.NET MVC4 - "Tiered" Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to do some kind of "tiered" validation in my form (don't know a better word). Example: the user inputs a password. This password might be

1. empty or too short (error condition red)
2. long enough but too weak (error condition yellow)
3. long and strong enough (green - go!)

Here's my concept for the html stuff (done before in another non-mvc non-dotnet project but can't tell how it was done since I was only responsible for the front-end html part):

```
<div class="input-box">
    <div class="hint">
        <span class="ok">OK</span>
        <span class="error_too_short">too short</span>
        ... other error condition-spans
    </div>
    <label....>
    <input....>
</div>
```

The "hint" spans are invisible first, then when an error condition arises one of them gets the "active" attribute added thus becomes visible. How can I achieve this in mvc4? jquery or custom validation? The validation should occur the moment the user leaves a field.

TIA

Heiko

Comment: Why don't you google for 'asp.net mvc input validation'?

Comment: @L-Three: you can be sure that I have already done so. There are tons of entries, but I have not found an entry who considers this specific scenario. Otherwise I would not have asked here.

Comment: I was just wondering why you try to invent your own way instead of using standard methods...

Comment: Because the standard way (as far as I recall it) is more an on/off kind of way: valid <-> not valid. I can return different validation messages, but not different validation states. What I want is some kind of alert like in star trek: red alert, yellow alert, etc. These states should activate the different <span..></span> fields by adding something like an "active" class attribute making *this* span visible belonging to *that* error state. Can this be done using standard methods? Maybe you explain...

Comment: In that case I would probably use jquery to manage the active classes depending on the result of ajax calls to controllers that execute the validation stuff and return the result.